# Delphi File Downloader Component

Tags: delphi, download

i need a file downloader component for Delphi . may you help me ?

Comment: Besides being able to download a file, what would this component do? Why should it be a component instead of, say, a library, or just a standalone function?

Comment: I haven't enough time to studying about it , so i need a ready component that works good

Comment: You don't have enough time to figure out what you need? How will you know whether you've found it, then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the high-level [`URLDownloadToFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(VS.85).aspx) function:

```
uses UrlMon;

...

URLDownloadToFile(nil, 'http://www.rejbrand.se/', 'C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\index.html', 0, nil);
```

Or, you could very easily write your own downloader function using the WinInet functions, something like

```
uses WinInet;

...

hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
try
  hURL := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar('http://' + Server + Resource), nil, 0, 0, 0);
  try
    repeat
      InternetReadFile(hURL, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BufferLen);

      ...
```

There is a lot of sample code here at SO. Use the search box above.

## Update

I wrote a small sample. You might want to execute this code in its own thread and let it ping back every 10 kB or so, so that you can provide the user with some progress bar, for instance.

```
function DownloadFile(const UserAgent, URL, FileName: string): boolean;
const
  BUF_SIZE = 4096;
var
  hInet, hURL: HINTERNET;
  f: file;
  buf: PByte;
  amtc: cardinal;
  amti: integer;
begin
  result := false;
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  try
    hURL := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar(URL), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    try
      GetMem(buf, BUF_SIZE);
      try
        FileMode := fmOpenWrite;
        AssignFile(f, FileName);
        try
          Rewrite(f, 1);
          repeat
            InternetReadFile(hURL, buf, BUF_SIZE, amtc);
            BlockWrite(f, buf^, amtc, amti);
          until amtc = 0;
          result := true;
        finally
          CloseFile(f);
        end;
      finally
        FreeMem(buf);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I do not understand what people have against TStream... for example FileMode := fmOpenWrite is not thread-safe because it sets a global variable.

Comment: Thank you , how can i set a progressbar for download and how can i get file size before download ?

Comment: @Idsandon: God, I hate it when people have *valid* arguments against the old-fashioned methods... :) (To be honest, I have never thought about this issue before, but it is certainly valid.)

Comment: nah, WinInet cries for its very own TStream-based wrapper. Also amtc amti variables could win unclarity award

Comment: These functions, by just being in imports table of the executable, will trigger antivirus software's heuristics. Either load them dynamically or use TIdHTTP solution (control also has a progress method).

Comment: @pani, I don't believe that. Even if it was true for a few days at some point in time.

Comment: @Cosmin Prundm, What exactly you don't believe? It is like this for at least 3 years!!!

Comment: @pani: Judging something as an potential virus simply for statically loading some API is a big mistake; I don't believe A/V companies are that dumb, not if they want to stay in business. What A/V software considered the use of this API a potential problem 3 years ago and still does today?

Comment: @Pani, please offer some proof. Either compile this code and post a screen shot of your antivirus program complaining about it, or post a link to someplace where someone else has performed a similar experiment.

Comment: Well compile this and upload to jotti or virustotal: program ProjectTest; uses WinInet; var temp: cardinal; begin InternetReadFile(nil, nil, 0, temp); end.

http://virusscan.jotti.org/en/scanresult/078d02fb1962807d2cd3e51ba16a5942b3013818 and http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=ed63a29d3d92b6efe056cd427b7ac5d3d8dd5b93844d0a973a3ad84a8aefbae6-1293226826

Comment: @pani: I just compiled *my* code above, and in `FormCreate`, it downloads `example.com` to `C:\test.file`. There result, from VirusTotal, is 0 issues: http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=8e26919ffe41235141116304f9fb81fcea1ba9adb4904f85ed3a4f8cbf5501d7-1293228283

In addition, empty VCL projects have been known to be reported as viruses...

Answer (score 7):

You can also make this with Indy :

```
procedure DownloadHTTP(const AUrl : string; DestStream: TStream);
begin
  with TIdHTTP.Create(Application) do
  try
      try
        Get(AUrl,DestStream);
      except
        On e : Exception do
          MessageDlg(Format('Erreur : %s',[e.Message]), mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
  finally
      Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want quick download, you can also use [Clever Internet Suite](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/inetsuite/suitemmd.asp)

Comment: This way is too slow and i can't change the chunk value !

Comment: Too slow? How? And what's "the chunk value"? You never mentioned that in your question.

Comment: I never find Indy slow but if you need more fast component, I add a new link for you (it seems to be more quick)