# Get web page in Delphi

Tags: delphi, parsing, download

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Downloading a file in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506251/downloading-a-file-in-delphi)
>   [Delphi File Downloader Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521535/delphi-file-downloader-component)

Hello everyone,
 I'm trying to develop a Delphi 7 app which would serve as a currency database or something close to it (don't ask me why, I'm doing it just for money:) ). So current task is to download a web page containing currency list from a server and extract this list to the database. 
Is it possible and what tools should one need to accimplish it? I know php, but writing php gui seems something crazy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506251/downloading-a-file-in-delphi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521535/delphi-file-downloader-component, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Andreas comments, you can also check out Delphi.About.com, there is an example there to download a file and show a progressbar: http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip0903_2.htm

> "If you need to save the contents of a specified URL to a file - and be able to track the download progress, use the TDownLoadURL Delphi action
>   While TDownLoadURL is writing to the specified file, it periodically generates an OnDownloadProgress event, so that you can provide users with feedback about the process.
>   Here's an example - note that you must include the unit ExtActns in the uses clause."

```
uses ExtActns, ...

type
   TfrMain = class(TForm)
   ...
   private
     procedure URL_OnDownloadProgress
        (Sender: TDownLoadURL;
         Progress, ProgressMax: Cardinal;
         StatusCode: TURLDownloadStatus;
         StatusText: String; var Cancel: Boolean) ;
   ...

implementation
...

procedure TfrMain.URL_OnDownloadProgress;
begin
   ProgressBar1.Max:= ProgressMax;
   ProgressBar1.Position:= Progress;
end;

function DoDownload;
begin
   with TDownloadURL.Create(self) do
   try
     URL:='http://0.tqn.com/6/g/delphi/b/index.xml';
     FileName := 'c:\ADPHealines.xml';
     OnDownloadProgress := URL_OnDownloadProgress;

     ExecuteTarget(nil) ;
   finally
     Free;
   end;
end;
```