# TWebBrowser without parent window

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am trying to use TWebBrowser in Console/Service type of application (without any windows). Navigate is definitely doing something, but it never calls onDocumentComplete. Is there any other way to get access to IHTMLDocument2 of some URL?

Thank you.

Comment: What, specifically, are you hoping to accomplish? TWebBrowser might not be your only option here.

Comment: If you want to download some HTML or whatever through HTTP you are better of with a HTTP Client like one from Indy

Comment: Do you just want to download something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521535/delphi-file-downloader-component/4521575#4521575

Comment: @Michael Madsen, I would prefer to have IE for redirects, cookies and so on. Plus, ultimate goal is to extract some text information from the web page. So, access to DOM would be pretty useful here.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, I am trying to implement "content watchdog". We have old in-house project that does the task. But it is not precise enough and gives ton of false-positives, when site changes some scripts on the web page.

My thanks to everyone who sent the response. I will try Handle Needed method. Thou, it might be an issue if engine is used from non-interactive Service. We'll see.

Comment: Serge - did you ever get this to work?  I too have the same need.  I am trying to create a service to verify if url links exist on certain pages.  While Indy works fine for the main page, there could be tons of embedded java script (one of the more common is Disqus) which Indy would miss.  I tried the HandleNeeded but this did not work.  I also tried making a form too.  No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the TWebBrowser instance (e.g. with Navigate2), call its HandleNeeded method. This will allocate an 'invisible' parent window handle and straighten out any event issues.

Comment: `HandleNeeed()` does not allocate a hidden parent window.  It requires the `Parent` property to be assigned beforehand.  The browser is a visual control.  It needs a visual parent window.

Comment: It calls TWinControl.CreateHandle, which calls CreateWnd, which creates the needed visual window handle. (though 0x0 pixels big, and not visible, but still visual)